# How can i simulate files download like offline mode?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method to download files using `Webclient`:

```
private void fileDownloadRadar()
{
    if (Client.IsBusy == true)
    {
        Client.CancelAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        Client.DownloadFileAsync(myUri, combinedTemp);
    }
 }
```

I also have a `checkBox3`. If is checked then *simulate downloads* otherwise *don't simulate*.

```
private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox3.Checked)
    {

    }
}
```

On my hard disk i have many `GIF files` that i want to simulate them as downloading files like i'm using the `webclient` to download them.

Maybe to create a new method something like:

```
OfflineFileDownloadRadar()
```

And using the `WebClient` or some other way to simulate downloading the files in my hard disk like they were on a website.

Is there any way to make this simulation ?

Comment: Why not set up a local test server on your dev box and download them from the local box? It's what I do. For web stuff, I set up a local web on IIS on the box. For other things (like legacy FTP stuff), I set up the appropriate local accounts and services. Once I'm done testing, I just turn all that stuff off until I need it again.

Comment: You should elaborate on why you want to "simulate" and exactly how you want this simulation to behave. Do you want to simulate for testing purposes, or to allow for an alternative source of data in real-world scenarios, or something else? If for testing purposes, do you want the simulation to have latency similar to when using WebClient, or is it okay for the simulated download to complete quickly (i.e. at disk speed instead of Internet speed)?

Comment: Peter the simulation should be for a testing puposes. I thought now maybe i can use my SkyDrive account to upload some images to the SkyDrive creating new directory for the images and only to change in my program the Uri address ? So it will use the same way it is using today with the webclient and everything and only to change the Uri address. Is it good idea ?

Comment: An easy way to simulate this might be to just up a local developer IIS instance on your machine, then go into your hosts file and add something like `www.mytest.com   127.0.0.1` then you can just add a gif file to your local IIS folder. Then you can test by going to `www.mytest.com/myimage.gif`